# Can I scale out the mysql charm instead of adding another database?

Tags: mysql, juju

I have question how to scaling mysql service because I make deployment from here: https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/charms-deploying

And I have wordpress and mysql related but is there possible to scale only mysql? When I add-unit mysql I recieve another mysql database instead.

And is there possible to write charm where nodes will be share performance? I have server based app(making some calcutaions and recievieng data and send data to clients) in java. Is there possible to scale up this application and make it faster(I mean manage more clients)?

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL charm supports replication.  It's a little non-intuitive in that you're not really adding units to the primary service. Instead, you're adding slaves.  Here's one way to do that:

```
juju deploy mysql masterdb
juju deploy mysql slavedb -n3
juju add-relation masterdb:master slavedb:slave
```

and then relate it to services like MediaWiki that support MySQL read-only replicas:

```
juju deploy mediawiki -n8
juju add-relation masterdb:db mediawiki:db
juju add-relation slavedb:db mediawiki:slave
...
```

The charm doesn't currently support any master-master replication.

Comment: But it's maiking only copy I presume, yes? Is there any charm that I can test if more nodes are better than one?(I mean performance)